# Polynomial Functions - Rational Root Theorem to find Zeros

Tags: polynomials, roots

I apologize if the level of this question is too low for this forum, it's my first time posting. I was reading about how to find the zeroes of a polynomial function, and I came across using the rational roots theorem and synthetic division. After finding possible zeros, it says that I have to divide the original polynomial with one of the possible zeros, to make sure the remainder of that division is $0$. But, why does this specifically pertain to finding the zeros? If `x mod y=0` then, $y$ can certainly be a factor of $x$ as well, without being a $0$. Any clarification on the theorem will be much appreciated. Thanks!

~Carpetfizz

Comment: Somewhat unreasonable, if one has verified by substitution that $a$ is a root, dividing the polynomial by $x-a$ to check is too much work. However, If $P(x)$ is our polynomial, and $a$ is a root, it may be worthwhile to calculate $Q(x)=\frac{P(x)}{x-a}$, and then look for roots of $Q(x)$. If $P(x)$ was a cubic, then $Q(x)$ is a quadratic, easy to find roots of.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, that helps a little, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P(x)=a_nx^n +a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots +a_1x +a_0$, where all the coefficients are integers.

The Rational Roots Theorem says that all rational roots of this polynomial have shape $\frac{p}{q}$, where $p$ divides $a_0$ and $q$ divides $a_n$. Please note that possibly $p$ is negative.

For any specific integers $a_n$ and $a_0$, this produces a finite list of **candidates**, and we can usually check them all without difficulty by substituting.

The polynomial need not have any rational roots, though cubics in school exercises usually do!

If our polynomial is $P(x)$, and $a$ is a root, then $x-a$ divides $P(x)$. It seems to be a bit of a waste of time to divide $P(x)$ by $x-a$ to check whether $a$ really is a root, since "plugging in" is easier, and less likely to lead to error.

However, synthetic division can be useful. Suppose for example $P(x)$ is a cubic, and we have found a rational root $a$, and only one. We can then calculate $Q(x)=\frac{P(x)}{x-a}$ and obtain a quadratic. Roots of this can then be easily found using the Quadratic Formula.

**Remark:** We are not dividing the polynomial by one of the zeros, we are dividing by the linear polynomial $x-a$, where $a$ is a zero of the polynomial.

I do not understand the modular arithmetic part of the question. The ideas of modular arithmetic *can* be extended to polynomials, even polynomials with real coefficients, and much more. So we can say that $a$ is a root if and only if $P(x)\equiv 0\pmod{x-a}$. That is just a restatement of the result that $x-a$ divides $P(x)$.